# How to find contours in an image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

I need to find all contours in an image. I know the whole findcontours () and drawContours () thing, but its using the Canny edge detector that I am having trouble with. To use find contours, you either need to use canny edge detection or threshold the image. I cannot threshold the image because this would result in several edges getting blurred out ("merging" of the edges). So I decided to use Canny Edge detection. However, when I do use it instead of getting perfect edges, I get a variety of lines with gaps in them. This prevents me from getting good contours For example instead of getting the edges of a square, I would get 4 separate lines separated by small gaps resulting in me getting 4 contours instead of one. I tried dilating, opening, closing, Gaussian blurring and basically every morphological operator, but none of these are doing the job. Some do not merge the lines, while some merge the lines with non-relevant lines too. So I was wondering does anyone have a solution on how I can get actual contours from Canny Edge detection, or if not does someone have any alternatives to get all the contours from an image?

Comment: Posting sample images and code will be helpful for this one...

Comment: this is a very typical problem. playing around with the Canny parameters and the structural element of your morphology is the usual way to work around this. :)

Comment: Could you please make your comment as  an answer so I could select it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make blob, then contours come with it. :)

http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/